# The problem of displaying the "Jost" font in safari (for apple device)

Tags: css, ios, macos, fonts, tilde

There was a problem with a strange font display on apple devices. The font is in the fonts folder.
Website on tilde.
Has anyone encountered such a problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48SGE.png)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Jost";
  src: url("../fonts/Jost-Bold.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("../fonts/Jost-Bold.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```